# Javascript Notification Plugin - Capture message and params

Tags: control-panel, javascript, jquery, notification, messages

Please see [JavaScript Notification Plugin](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/cp_javascript/notification.html) for reference.

Question: Is it possible to "capture" the message and params of `$.ee_notice()` any time it's run in the CP?

I'd like to use [destroy](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/cp_javascript/notification.html#hiding-the-notifications) to hide the default notification but, still be able to use the message and params as I see fit via my own js/jQuery.

One place this appears to run is when saving publish layouts for what ever it's worth.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*update* 
looks like this task is not so simple as looks like - can't find where some notice even is registered (like for save custom field setting - looks like it is flashdata).

I made a quick example using [HubSpot Messaging](http://github.hubspot.com/messenger/) + ee_notice replacement as combination of JS & hooks - [CP Notice](https://github.com/MaxLazar/MX-CP-Notice)

[image]
[image]

*before*
Why just don't replace it with ext.?

```
function cp_js_end( $data ) {
    if ($this->EE->extensions->last_call !== FALSE)
    {
          $data = $this->EE->extensions->last_call;
    }

    $out = '
        $(function () {
            $.ee_notice = function (a, k) {
        alert(a);
        }
        $.ee_notice.destroy = function () {

    }

        });

    ';

     $data .= $out;

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Max! This was helpful and I've made some progress. I was able to get custom fields and add-on updates (enabling an extension for example) to work. I used the `$this->EE->session->flashdata;` inside `function cp_menu_array($menu){}`. The `$.ee_notice.destroy = funtion () {}` doesn't seem to matter on my end for publish layout updates. It's destroying the default notification with it our without it. I set a setting which allows user to turn it off which works with the flashdata version but not the $.ee_notice version for some reason.